# Redirect a frontend URL to another backend webserver

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver, playframework

I'm using a framework that uses a full-stack to display all its webpages. This runs standard on port **9000**. Very fine, but when going into production, the server seems to block everything except a few standard ports.

So therefore, the framework (Play framework), advises you to do this in your front-end webserver (in my case Apache2).

file: play.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://avon.ugent.be
  CustomLog /var/www/log/proxy-access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/www/log/proxy-error.log
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Location /dev/app>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Test Omgeving"
    AuthUserFile /var/trac/htpasswd
    Require valid-user

    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This of course requires the **mod_proxy** module, that is being enabled with `a2enmod mod_proxy`. (I run this on a Debian distro)

The idea is to run two webservers, one front-end and one back-end with the application. 
The reloading of the apache webserver works fine, the site is enabled and everything, but when I surf to the `http://my.website.com/dev/app` url, it renders a 404... Suggestions what's going wrong?

---

EDIT3:
After 10+ hours of trying it boils down to this:
I found the debugging command (finally :p) and this is the output:

```
apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server avon.ugent.be (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost avon.ugent.be (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost avon.ugent.be (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/play.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

Which indicates that the virtual server is indeed being added to the configuration.
But still, it renders a 404. Now, somewhere i've read that's because there is no index.html in that path. Is that necessary if you just want to use a reverse proxy?

Comment: In your actual config, does the `ServerName` directive match the URL you're requesting? Your example shows `ServerName playtest` and in this case should be `ServerName my.website.com` if you are accessing `http://my.website.com/dev/app`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I was under the impression that the servername was arbirtrary, sorry :) I edited the file in my front post. It didn't solve the problem though, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: edit 3... This is getting tremendously annoying... thanks for the help so far (not sarcastic!), hoping for a solution any time now!

Answer (score 2):

For a start please try using `Location` instead of `Directory`. Directory is used for identifying directory paths on the filesystem not paths relative to the document root.

```
<Location '/dev/app'>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Test Omgeving"
  AuthUserFile /var/trac/htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves indeed the authentication issue, the 404 remains though.
But great that one already thing works :)

Comment: To figure out where the 404 is coming from (the backend proxy server or the apache instance) can you tail the access/error logs on the backend server to see what's being requested there and whether it's got any useful error messages?

Comment: I'm going to take a look into the logging of the back-end framework, the thing is, it's all supposed to be "full-stack", so the backend webserver is hidden for the developer. But there is support for logging, so I'll start there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It should prompt for the username/password and then pass the request to http://127.0.0.1:9000.  In my case, Apache gives a `"Service Temporarily Unvavailable"`, which you should get as well if you turn off the application running on port `9000`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.website.com

    <Location /dev/app>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Test Omgeving"
      AuthUserFile passwd/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user

      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you still get a 404, can you confirm that it's not the backend server sending it?

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I still get the 404, but when I'm executing `lynx http://localhost:9000`, that works fine. So the server is indeed sending every response. So the problem lies between apache requesting pages from play...

Comment: The strangest thing... When I execute this `lynx http://127.0.0.1:9000`, it keeps waiting for a request... I'm trying to look in some play configuration files... I'll keep you posted

Comment: But when I try to edit the `ProxyPass` directive by removing the "http://", it generates an error indicating that the paths have to be absolute...

Comment: That is correct, the `http://` is needed.  The problem you are having with accessing `http://127.0.0.1:9000` versus `127.0.0.1:9000` is not something in Apache.  Unless you have Apache set to `Listen 9000`, which by the sounds of it, you do not, that is more likely to be a problem with the backend application/server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you suggest I do now?  I'm running out of options :)

Comment: Add the following below the `ServerName` line: `CustomLog logs/proxy-access.log common`.  Update the `logs/proxy-access.log` according to your log directory, and `common` is a default log format and should work.  If your requests are making it through the Apache host, you should see some log entries with a response code, probably the second to last item on the log line.

Comment: thanks clmarquart, I tried the logging command, and redirected the logs to /var/www/logs. The logfile is created, but it does not contain any lines. I tried restarting, enabling/disabling, reloading... It remains empty.